# How can I accept a random object as a dynamic parameter to my controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm not quite sure how to ask this question.  I actually had this working before, and then I made some seemingly trivial changes and broke it, and I'm not sure how to make it work.

What I want to do is have a dynamic object parameter in my controller action, so that when some serialized form data is posted to it, the dynamic object will automatically bind to the various properties sent to it.

I've looked around at a bunch of questions, but most were old and indicated that a custom model binder was needed, but I would like to reiterate that this was working without a custom model binder.  I was just including a formData in my post data and catching it with a dynamic formData parameter.

So under what conditions does ASP.NET assume this is what I want?

Comment: There is no way this could have worked, since the process of model binding (using the `DefaultModelBinder`) works by first initializing the classes defined in the parameters (using `Activator.GetInstance`) then finding the key/value pairs from  form data (and other values from query string values etc) and setting the corresponding properties of the model. There must have been something else you were doing.

Comment: I am not asking you to inspect my code for errors, I am asking under what conditions the default model binder will bind post data to a dynamic object.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Post(JObject dynamicJSON)
{
  dynamic myObj = dynamicJSON;
  int id = myObj.Id
}
```

JObject class is part of Newtonsoft.JSON library

Answer (score 0):

i was goggling one day i see that threat..its working to

> controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoSomething(string a, string b, dynamic c)
{
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

> Then do it dynamic model binder interface declaration

```
public class DynamicJsonAttribute : CustomModelBinderAttribute
{
    public override IModelBinder GetBinder()
    {
        return new DynamicJsonBinder(MatchName);
    }

    public bool MatchName { get; set; }
}
```

> and here is implementation

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Helpers;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class DynamicJsonBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private readonly bool matchName;

    public DynamicJsonBinder(bool matchName)
    {
        this.matchName = matchName;
    }

    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var contentType = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType;
        if (!contentType.StartsWith("application/json", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return null;

        string bodyText;
        using (var stream = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream)
        {
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                bodyText = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(bodyText)) return null;

        var desiralized = Json.Decode(bodyText);

        if (!matchName) return desiralized;

        var members = desiralized.GetDynamicMemberNames() as IEnumerable&lt;string&gt;;
        return members == null
            || members.Contains(bindingContext.ModelName)
            ? desiralized[bindingContext.ModelName] : null;
    }
}
```

you ve been hacked ---happy coding

anyway i was read the thread from this url---[look it out](http://blog.duc.as/2011/06/07/making-mvc-3-a-little-more-dynamic/)